# Problems with Keycloak URI redirection

Tags: keycloak

I'm developing an application where the front-end communicates directly with Keycloak, and when the user is not logged in, I redirect them to the Keycloak login page. So far so good. However, I'm facing a problem. I can't get Keycloak to redirect the logged-in user to a specific address, which is located elsewhere. So, to provide context, here's what's happening:

- The domain where the application is hosted is https://www.myapplication.com
- The domain where Keycloak is hosted is https://mysecurity.security.keycloak.com

The user accesses https://www.myapplication.com. If they're not logged in, they are redirected to https://mysecurity.keycloak.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=account-console&redirect_uri=https://mysecurity.keycloak.com/realms/myrealm/account&state=xxxxx&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=xxxxx&prompt=none&code_challenge=xxxxx&code_challenge_method=S256 where they log in. Note that the redirect_uri is set as the default path defined by Keycloak. If I go into the client settings and add the redirection URL https://www.myapplication.com/welcome to the "Valid redirect URIs" field, Keycloak presents me with the error "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri." Is it possible to achieve this with Keycloak? If so, how should I configure it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect URI in the initial auth link should not be pointing to redirect_uri=https://mysecurity.keycloak.com/realms/myrealm/account, instead it should point back to your application.

This redirect_URI needs to match the redirect URL defined inside KeyCloak EXACTLY.

The URL should not be your welcome page, it should point to where KeyCloak should post the authorization code and other information. So your client can then retrieve the tokens from KeyCloak. what this url is, all depends on what libraries you are using.

If you use ASP.NET Core, it is typically /signin-oidc

Comment: Hey Tore, thank you very much for your help. So, does it mean that for me to get the URL provided in "Valid redirect URIs" to work, I need the website https://www.myapplication.com to be able to receive the authentication data that Keycloak generates after authentication?

Comment: Yes, from the URL in your question, it says  ..response_type=code..., this means that KeyKloak will return a "code" that your openid-connect library in your code can use to exchange it for the real tokens.... So, the redirect URI where this code should be sent to. The exact URL depends on the library that you use.